# XAML advice for implementing tab-bar

Tags: c#, .net, xaml, user-interface, maui

Is it possible to achieve the following visual effect in .NET MAUI/XAML:
The main concern is the outline (or lack thereof on the bottom) of the selected tab and the underline of the unselected tabs.

[image: Tab-Bar example 1]
[image: Tab-Bar example 2]

The goal is to be able to define an arbitrary number of Tabs for the application.
Is this possible with XAML alone?
Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: it is theoretically possible with XAML (at least when we are talking about WPF XAML). Now since you mentioned MAUI, that will strongly depend on the target platform (short answer is that it is unlikely to accomplish cross-platform with only XAML)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Do you have an idea how to go about implementing such an effect? XAML or otherwise?

Comment: To answer that I would need to know the platforms you are targeting this app.

Comment: In general Windows, iOS and MacCatalyst. However, any advice on how to approach this would be helpful, as I'm not yet very familiar with "advanced" XAML

Answer (score 0):

If I had to create custom controls I would go with the [GraphicsView](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/graphics/draw?view=net-maui-7.0).

Create a custom control `Tab` with a canvas that draw it in function of it state, you can use `StackLayout` to stack them and `TapGestureRecognizer` to manage clicks events.

One of the main problem of a GraphicsView is that you can't attach click event to shapes you are drawing (one solution [there](https://github.com/dotnet/Microsoft.Maui.Graphics/discussions/332)) so you can't be really precise on the events if you don't want to manage bounding box yourself.

Or you can just use `ImageButton` for the tabs with a label in front for the text, it would be way easier but less flexible (tabs should all be the same sizes).